# Knowing that $a+b\equiv 1 \pmod{7^{n+1}}$ show that $a^7+b^7\equiv 1 \pmod{7^{n+2}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Knowing that $a,b$ are prime integers and $a+b\equiv 1 \pmod{7^{n+1}}$ show that $a^7+b^7\equiv 1 \pmod{7^{n+2}}$

I used $a^7+b^7=(a+b)(a^6-a^5b+a^4b^2-a^3b^3+a^2b^4-ab^5+b^6)$ and tried to show that $(a^6-a^5b+a^4b^2-a^3b^3+a^2b^4-ab^5+b^6)\equiv 1 \pmod 7$ but after some trial and error I figured that it might not help as much as I thought. I also tried to show that $ a^7+b^7-1\equiv 0 \pmod{7^{n+2}}$, but I got stuck.

How should I solve this?

Comment: What you should prove is that $a^6-a^5b+\ldots+b^6\equiv 1\pmod{7^{n+2}}$.

Comment: You can prove that if $a+b\equiv 0\pmod{7^{n+1}}$ then $a^7+b^7\equiv 0\pmod{7^{n+2}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true. Take $a=7, b=43$. Then $a+b\equiv 1\bmod 49$, but $a^7+b^7\equiv 295\bmod 343$.

In fact, I would think that the primality or otherwise of $a$ and $b$ is irrelevant, given that we are only interested in their values mod $7^{n+1}$; but perhaps if you require that they be co-prime to $7$, your result might hold.

**Edited to add:** No, that doesn't work either. Take $a=53,b=193$ (both prime, and both co-prime to $7$). Then $a+b\equiv 1\bmod 49$, but $a^7+b^7\equiv 134\bmod 343$. So it seems your claim is simply false.